# How to select a TVS Diode for LM74700

Tags: diodes, tvs

[lm74700](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm74700-q1.pdf?ts=1681038897483&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F)
I looked into the basics for a TVS diode; the important factors that needed to be considered are the breakdown voltage i.e. when the TVS diode becomes 'visible to the rest of the circuit or when it starts to conduct.

Secondly, the clamping voltage of the diode, i.e., when exposed to ESD, say 600 V then it clamps it to a safe level which should be lesser than the absolute maximum voltage of the rest of the internal circuitry.

I couldn't understand the plot and the calculations performed while choosing and esd diode.
For 24 V voltage protection they used a pair of unidirectional TVS diode (which behave as if they were bi-directional as they are connected like so).

"The breakdown voltage of the TVS+ should be higher than 48 V jump start voltage, less than the absolute maximum ratings of anode and enable pin of LM74700-Q1 (65 V) and should withstand 65 V suppressed load dump. The breakdown voltage of TVS- should be lower than maximum reverse battery voltage –32 V, so that the TVS- is not damaged due to long time exposure to reverse connected battery.
During ISO 7637-2 pulse 1, the input voltage goes up to –600 V with a generator impedance of 50 Ω. This translates to 12 A flowing through the TVS-. The clamping voltage of the TVS- cannot be same as that of 12 V
battery protection circuit. Because during the ISO 7637-2 pulse, the anode to cathode voltage seen is equal to
(-TVS clamping voltage + output capacitor voltage). For a 24 V battery application, the maximum battery voltage is 32 V, then the clamping voltage of the TVS- should not exceed, 75 V – 32 V = 43 V.
Single bi-directional TVS cannot be used for 24 V battery protection because breakdown voltage for TVS+ ≥ 65 V, maximum clamping voltage is ≤ 43 V and the clamping voltage cannot be less than the breakdown voltage.
Two un-directional TVS connected back-back needs to be used at the input. For positive side TVS+, SMBJ58A with the breakdown voltage of 64.4 V (minimum), 67.8 (typical) is recommended. For the negative side TVS-,
SMBJ26A with breakdown voltage close to 32 V (to withstand maximum reverse battery voltage –32 V) and maximum clamping voltage of 42.1 V is recommended"

So for positive ESS discharge into the circuit TVS diode should only conduct above > 48 V (as this may be used to jump-start the battery. Should be able to withstand 65 V of suppressed load dump, does this mean that it needs to clamp 65 V to above >48 V?

Breakdown of TVS- (for negative discharge) should be less than -32 V (as this may be supplied by the battery) when connected in reverse polarity say at -40 V the diode starts to conduct.(Would it be fine?)

Need help with the calculations in the above-quoted paragraph.

edit: I might have misframed the question, this is not a 'design' question per se but more of how did they decide the clamping voltages. If you look at the quoted paragraph they come up with ranges within which the diode should clamp excess potential. I just want to understand how they arrived at those values. I have a rough idea but I'd prefer if someone could explain it in easy terms.

Circuit diagram:
[image]

Comment: A circuit diagram is needed showing the position(s) of the TVS diode(s).

Comment: added as given in the datasheet

Comment: The battery and Cin will totally soak up any ESD energy so please show the scenarios you are considering schematically and individually. You need to list the threats not just as a voltage but as a waveform in series with an impedance. You can't figure out what TVS is needed without full knowledge of the threats. What component is the weakest link regarding over-voltage?

Comment: The input is the 'battery', as per the given standard, an esd of -600V with an impedance of 50 ohms is given at the circuit's input. We're trying to protect the 74700 IC

Comment: You need to work at this in a more disciplined way. All the detail I asked for is important in order to be able to arrive at the right TVS diode to use. For instance, when you say the ESD threat is -600 volts, I don't recognize that ESD standard hence, much more detail needed.

Comment: Sorry i think i might have misframed the question, this is not a 'design' question per se but more of how did they decide the clamping voltages. If you look at the quoted paragraph they come up with ranges within which the diode should clamp excess potential. I just want to understand how they arrived at those values. I have a rough idea but i'd prefer if someone could explain it in easy terms

Comment: What’s your load?

Comment: I'm so sorry, by load if you mean what we're trying to protect then it's the IC itself. 
I might not be able to answer clarifying questions as I myself haven't been able to understand it. If you could just go over section 10.1.1.4 or page 18 on the datasheet you might understand what I'm asking or rather trying to ask.